# How do I update para.text in shoes (ruby)

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I am trying to create simple GUI that will display some data based on a single field that a user enters

this is the code I'm using to display the data

```
Shoes.app {
    background "#EFC"
    border("#BE8", strokewidth: 6)
    stack(margin: 12) {
        @here=para "Eneter your summoner name"
        flow {
            @sumName=edit_line
            @push=button "Enter"
            @push.click {
                setup(@sumName.text)
            }
        }
    }
    #Champion Stats Table
    flow{
        $table = [[]]
        i = 0
        #Name
        stack(:width => 100){
            $table[i][0] = para "Champion", margin: 4
            $Summoner.rankedChamps.each do |c|
                $table[i][0] = para c.name, margin: 4
            end
            i+=1
        }
        i = 0
        #Wins
        stack(:width => 50){
            $table[i][1] = para "Wins", margin: 4
            $Summoner.rankedChamps.each do |c|
                $table[i][1] = para c.wins.to_s, margin: 4
            end
            i+=1
        }
        i = 0
        #Loses
        stack(:width => 50){
            $table[i][1] = para "Loses", margin: 4
            $Summoner.rankedChamps.each do |c|
                $table[i][2] = para c.loses.to_s, margin: 4
            end
            i+=1
        }
        i = 0
        #KDA
        stack(:width => 50){
            $table[i][1] = para "KDA", margin: 4
            $Summoner.rankedChamps.each do |c|
                $table[i][3] = para c.KDA.to_s, margin: 4
            end
            i+=1
        }
    }
```

When the user clicks the enter button the `$Summoner` object is updated properly however I can not figure out how to update all of the para's text feilds

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you're trying to do but here's one way :

```
Shoes.app {
    background "#EFC"
    border "#BE8", strokewidth: 6
    stack margin: 12 do
        para "Enter your summoner name"
        flow {
            sumName = edit_line
            button "Enter" do
                setup(sumName.text)
            end
        }
    end

    flow do
        stack(:width => 100) {
            @para1 = para "Champion", margin: 4
        }
        stack(:width => 50) {
            @para2 = para "Wins", margin: 4
        }
        stack(:width => 50) {
            @para3 = para "Loses", margin: 4
        }
        stack(:width => 50) {
            @para4 = para "KDA", margin: 4
        }
    end
}
```

Then probably in your setup method update your paras with the text setter method, for example :  `@para3.text = your_text_data`
Build your gui layout, then later when user name is available update needed fields